# Beginner's dillema about calling MVC 5 action using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, asp.net-mvc-5

I've started to learn TypeScript and I know how to include jQuery inside its classes. In that way I'm able to make ajax call to MVC5 action and use returned data further.

But, is it possible to not use jQuery ajax calls, but use some TypeScript's mechanism for that purpose? What about async/await?

Comment: you can use async,await with fetch api which does not require a lot of promise `.then( `callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's better not to use jquery ajax with typescript in this case to make the async calls . You can use `async`/`await` and `fetch` api to call your controller action methods which returns JSON data like below

```
async getDataUsingAsync() {
    let response = await fetch('path-to-controller-action');
    let data= await response.json(); 
    console.log(data); 
}
```

async/await is available from Typescript 2.1 version.

check out the below links for more reference

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/async-and-await-in-typescript 
http://blog.ctaggart.com/2016/12/fetch-api-via-typescript-async.html

Comment: Ok. It sounds very good. But, can I use TypeScript that supports async/await in VS 2013?

Comment: not sure about VS2013 version but you need to have the proper version of Nodejs installed with typescript 2.1x. If you mean intellisense then I think it's supported for VS.

Comment: @tesicg great .. can you please upvote this answer if it helps.

Comment: @tesicg i mean the upvote also , i can see the accepted answer . you need to click the upside arrow :)

Comment: Do you mean like this?